# Which motor would work best as a generator?

Tags: motor, ac, dc

i've been doing a lot of research into motors to use as a generator in a medium sized wind turbine project.

I am lost as to what to do, will a large AC motor with a bridge rectifier be a good approach? They seem relatively inexpensive compared to DC motors. I want the set up to charge a 12V battery. Will this require some sort of controller? Which motors will work best? Will a single phase AC motor with a bridge rectifier be able to charge a battery if used as a generator?

Comment: Your question is terribly under-specified.

Comment: How much power do you need to produce? What are the physical size constraints on the motor? What is the amp-hour rating on the battery?

Comment: The question is missing quite a lot of important information. For example how big is the wind-turbine, and what range of much power do you expect it to capture? What is the battery spec., and how quickly must it be charged? It covers a wide range of topics which is not a good fit for the site. It helps to be more specific. We also expect to see some evidence of research, to discourage trolls, and demonstrate the poster is committed to getting an answer. Please read the [help] to learn how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 2):

What size do you consider "medium", in say kW or W? What style wind turbine is it- fast rotational or slow?

You could use an AC motor but you would likely need a gearbox to ramp up the rotational speed of the power transfer between the wind turbines main propellant shaft and the motor. 
AC motors are indeed cheaper (due to mass manufacturing and the common place nature) but have a higher operating speed. What type of AC motor are you looking at too? A synchronous machine or induction?

A DC motor is probably the best bet for your application because the world of motors can be quite complex. A controller will be needed to charge your batteries and to prevent over charging and excess power dumping.

Also yes, a single phase ac motor with bridge rectifer would be able to do such but see above queries!

Comment: Maybe about 250-500W. I'd like it to be a fairly slow rotating windmill due to the fact that the winds can be very rough here at times. I will go for a dc motor then! What would be the minimum voltage/amperage rating you'd recommend?

Answer (score 1):

The DC motor is best suited for a generator. It'll produce current, even if the speed of the rotation is somewhat less. When you use a single phase motor, you'll need to rotate it at a speed higher than the motors synchronous speed to generate energy. When the rotation speed of the motor drops to speed, less than synchronous speed, it'll stop to generate energy.

For a DC motor, it'll keep on generating energy and the voltage at the output depends on the speed of rotation. Even if the speed is reduced, you'll still get energy from DC motor with reduced voltage (I'm talking about DC with permanent magnets

In the case of wind driven type, I'll recommend you to use a DC motor with permanent magnets or either excited externally because we cannot expect the wind to be constant blowing. It'll vary due to many factors.

If you prefer engine driven, then single phase motor is good or even DC motor also. We can expect constant speed from a engine. You need a voltage regulator to get a constant voltage at the output. The output from a motor is pulsating DC, but it still is DC only. Capacitor in parallel with the output of generator will help to smoothing the pulsating voltage. Higher the capacitance, greater is the smoothing of output DC voltage. Then feed this smoothed voltage to a 12V voltage regulator. That's it.

If you want to monitor the voltage, you can use controllers. Otherwise, don't make it too complicated with controllers. Just a simple setup is okay to use.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a small power experiment, a stepper motor generates good power at lower rpm (revolutions per minute). Stepper motors can be obtained from old broken printers and scanners. [This](https://www.instructables.com/Bike-light-generator/) is one instructable that makes a light glow with stepper motor generator.